# OpenCV HoughCircles

Tags: c++, xcode, opencv

Im using Xcode and c++

I have copied the HoughCircles code from the [OpenCV documentation](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/feature_detection.html?highlight=circle%20detection#cv-houghcircles):

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include <math.h>

using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Mat img, gray;
    if( argc != 2 && !(img=imread(argv[1], 1)).data)
        return -1;
    cvtColor(img, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    // smooth it, otherwise a lot of false circles may be detected
    GaussianBlur( gray, gray, Size(9, 9), 2, 2 );
    vector<Vec3f> circles;
    HoughCircles(gray, circles, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT,
                 2, gray->rows/4, 200, 100 );
    for( size_t i = 0; i < circles.size(); i++ )
    {
         Point center(cvRound(circles[i][0]), cvRound(circles[i][1]));
         int radius = cvRound(circles[i][2]);
         // draw the circle center
         circle( img, center, 3, Scalar(0,255,0), -1, 8, 0 );
         // draw the circle outline
         circle( img, center, radius, Scalar(0,0,255), 3, 8, 0 );
    }
    namedWindow( "circles", 1 );
    imshow( "circles", img );
    return 0;
}
```

then modified it like this:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    VideoCapture cap(0);
    if(!cap.isOpened())
        return -1;
    namedWindow( "circles", 1 );

    Mat img, gray;
    for( ;; )
    {

        cap >> img;
        vector<Vec3f> circles;      
        cvtColor(img, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
        GaussianBlur(gray, gray, Size(7,7), 1.5, 1.5);
        HoughCircles(img, circles, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 2, img->rows/4, 200, 100 );
        imshow( "circles", img );
        if(waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I get the error on both cases: error: base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'cv::Mat'
i then replace the -> with . and still get another error. This is the same with the code that i copied from the documentation.

My theory is that this happens because its not getting and image or somehting. but when i take the HoughCircles code out, the camera runs fine.

Any ideas please??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are both compiling errors? What error do you get when you use **.** to access *img* members? I'm certain that you should **not** use **->** in this case since *img* is not a pointer to Mat.

According to the [API reference manual](http://www.comp.leeds.ac.uk/vision/opencv/opencvref_cv.html#decl_cvHoughCircles) (you should take a loot at it):

```
void HoughCircles(Mat& image, vector<Vec3f>& circles, int method, double dp, double minDist, double param1=100, double param2=100, int minRadius=0, int maxRadius=0);
```

You must pass the memory address of the objects *img* and *circles* instead of passing the objects themselves.

You should do something like:

```
HoughCircles(&img, &circles, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 2, img.rows/4, 200, 100 );
```

Comment: yes both errors. the error i get when using . :

  "cv::HoughCircles(cv::Mat const&, __gnu_debug_def::vector<cv::Vec<float, 3>, std::allocator<cv::Vec<float, 3> > >&, int, double, double, double, double, int, int)", referenced from:

Answer (score 2):

First, you **must not** pass the address of `img` and `circles`.  HoughCircles takes references, not pointers.  If you attempt to pass `&img` and `&circles`, you will receive new and exciting type errors.  Your original code is correct in that regard.

**If** the function took pointers, it's declaration would have been:

```
void HoughCircles(Mat * image, vector<Vec3f> * circles, ...);
```

(Which it isn't -- I only mention it for anybody else that is confused by the `&` syntax in C++ function declarations)

Second, the `->` won't work because `Mat` is an object, not a pointer.  I'm only mildly surprised that the original documentation is wrong.  OpenCV's C++ interface (which you're using, if you're using `cv::Mat`) is kind of new, and stuff is still transitioning over.  This was probably copy/pasted from the C API documentation and that `->` was missed.

`img.rows` should work (and does work for me).  The error you provided for the `img.rows` case is not a full error, so I'm not sure why it is a complaint.

The only thing I'm seeing right now is that the `dp` parameter is a `double`, and you're passing an `int`.  Any C++ compiler I've ever used will do that upconversion for you, but if your compiler is in full paranoia mode, you might try changing 2 to 2.0.  (I really, really doubt that this is the problem, but without more details on the error, I don't see why you're getting compile-time errors)

At runtime, however, it's going to explode because you're passing HoughCircles your original BGR-based `img` instead of passing the single channel `gray`.