# Circle detection in ios application with OpenCV

Tags: c++, objective-c, iphone, opencv

I am an iOS application developer. I am new in OpenCV. I want to show the number of detected circle. My code is

```
Mat src, src_gray;
src=[self cvMatFromUIImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"images.jpeg"]];
cvtColor( src, src_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY );
GaussianBlur( src_gray, src_gray, Size(9, 9), 2, 2 );
std::vector<Vec3f> circles;
HoughCircles( src_gray, circles, HOUGH_GRADIENT, src_gray.rows/8, 200, 100, 0, 0 );
NSLog(@"No. of circle : %lu",circles.size());
```

But I am getting error:
1. 'Reference to 'Size' is ambigouas'.
2. Use of undeclared identifier 'CV_BGR2GRAY'.
Please any one guide me. I am waiting your response.

Comment: Did you tag your question with C++ and objective-C because you're mixing the languages?

Comment: Actually I have got the sample code from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387960/opencv-houghcircles?rq=1). For that I add the tag C++.

Comment: Okay, just wanted to make sure. I don't know obj-c so I can't help you with that

Answer (score 1):

Replace `CV_BGR2GRAY` with `6` and replace `Size(9,9)` with `org.opencv.core.Size(9,9)` or `cv::Size(9, 9)` if you've imported `<opencv2/highgui/ios.h>`. I can't confirm right now what will work, try it out.

Comment: I have used #include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"   


    
    But got an error  OpenCV Error: One of arguments' values is out of range (dp, min_dist, canny_threshold and acc_threshold must be all positive numbers) in cvHoughCircles, file /Users/vp/work/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/hough.cpp, line 1041
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type cv::Exception: /Users/vp/work/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/hough.cpp:1041: error: (-211) dp, min_dist, canny_threshold and acc_threshold must be all positive numbers in function cvHoughCircles

Comment: Add an import "#import <opencv2/highgui/ios.h>" and replace Size(9,9) with cv::Size(9,9). See if that works.

Comment: For the other part, one of the arguments seems to be a negative value in HoughCircles() method. Try NSLogging all arguments and find out the argument which is entered negative.

Comment: But Same error occurred. In HoughCircles( src_gray, circles, HOUGH_GRADIENT, src_gray.rows/8, 200, 100, 0, 0 );  src_gray.rows/8 returns 252. I don't understand the error.    penCV Error: One of arguments' values is out of range (dp, min_dist, canny_threshold and acc_threshold must be all positive numbers) in cvHoughCircles

Comment: I think you should open a new question regarding this error and mark my answer correct if it helped you solving the error in your original question.